# Cannot use or import game classes in python

Tags: ironpython, monogame

Well I am struggling a lot with this issue. Since documentation is kinda non-existant on that matter and samples are scarce I have to tend to SO's community.

All I try is to get my model rotating around the Z-axis. For this I execute a python script each update:

```
renderComp = Entity.GetComponent[Render3DComponent]()
rot = renderComp.Rotation
renderComp.Rotation = rot.Z + MathHelper.ToRadians(0.01)
```

Whereas *Entity* is the game entity which is set before execute in the passed-thru scope. *Render3DComponent* is the component containing scale and rotation of the object (for now at least) and which renders the model. *Rotation* hereby is a *Vector3* which stores all three axis rotation values.

Well once I execute the script it tells me:

> IronPython.Runtime.UnboundNameException: 'name 'Render3DComponent' is
>   not defined'

My engine is set up like this:

```
_engine = Python.CreateEngine(options);

_engine.Runtime.IO.RedirectToConsole();
_engine.Runtime.LoadAssembly(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .First(a => a.FullName.Contains("MonoGame.Framework")));
_engine.Runtime.LoadAssembly(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
_engine.Runtime.LoadAssembly(Assembly.Load("mscorlib"));
_scope = _engine.CreateScope();
Console.SetOut(TextWriter.Synchronized(_engine.Runtime.IO.OutputWriter));
```

Thus should actually already have references to my game's assembly and MonoGame.
Nonetheless I also tried adding the references in the script (which seems to me as a performance issue after all):

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("AlphaEnergy.exe")
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("MonoGame.Framework.dll")

from AlphaEnergy import Render3DComponent

renderComp = Entity.GetComponent[Render3DComponent]()
rot = renderComp.Rotation
renderComp.Rotation = rot.Z + MathHelper.ToRadians(0.01)
```

But then I get this exception:

> IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: 'Cannot import name
>   Render3DComponent'

So I really don't get what the problem should be after all. I memorized this being easier to use...

And since I'm executing the script on-demand during runtime I can't get Visual Studio's debugger get to work with it.

Comment: The problem has been solved after hours of trial and error. You need to specify the full path thus import `System.IO` and use `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory` or similiar to get the full path. Moreover it's required to specify the full namespace (which Visual Studio falsely marked as error - Python support in non-python projects is ... terrible). To be more specific: `from 'full namespace' import 'your class'`